# Server side GCM returns error 400

Tags: java, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I am tring to implement GCM.
I wrote a test code to understand how it works, but I keep getting error 400 in the response.

I'm writing in Java (JDK 7).

I followed [this](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/) toturial on the subject.
I modified the given code there, and changed the use of ObjectMapper to Gson.

This is my code for the Data object:

```
public class Data {
   private ArrayList<String> registration_ids;

   public Data() {
      this.registration_ids = new ArrayList<String>();  
      this.registration_ids.add("APA91...");  // There is the real device registration id here.
   }
}
```

*I saw in the [server reference](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server-ref.html) that in HTTP protocol, I can send a message just with registration_ids. (All other are optional)

Here is the code to send the message:

```
public static void post(String apiKey, Data data){

    try{

        // 1. URL
        URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

        // 2. Open connection
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // 3. Specify POST method
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // 4. Set the headers
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + apiKey);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // 5. Add JSON data into POST request body

        // 5.1 Convert object to JSON
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Data>() {}.getType();

        String json = gson.toJson(data, type);

        System.out.println(json);
        // The printed string is
        // {"registration_ids":["APA91..."]}
        // with the correct registration id of my device.


        // 5.2 Get connection output stream
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


        // 5.3 Copy Content "JSON" into
        wr.writeUTF(json);

        // 5.4 Send the request
        wr.flush();

        // 5.5 close
        wr.close();

        // 6. Get the response
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // 7. Print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know that error 400 means a json problem, but I tried many variations for the data I'm sending, and none of them worked (I created the string manually, without gson, in these tests).

This is the error message I'm receiving:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>       at POST2GCM.post(POST2GCM.java:64)
>       at App.main(App.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
>       at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>       at POST2GCM.post(POST2GCM.java:59)
>       ... 1 more

Can you please help me with this issue?
Thank you very much,
Yuval.

Comment: You can use the Sender and Message helper classes. They will do all the JSON translation and sending for you such that you do not need to handle the output stream yourself. See them in action [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendMessageServlet.java#L121-L124).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in DataOutputStream.writeChars() and DataOutputStream.writeUTF().

Thanks to the link given by [@Koh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954771/koh), I changed the write command in the post function to:

```
wr.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Now the message is being sent successfully!