# Why FCM push notification shows java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The following output I am getting:

> Data   {"id":"1","notification":"{\"UserTo\":36,\"Message\":\"Your
>   Profile is sortlisted Byramesh sable\",\"UserFromName\":\"ramesh
>   sable\",\"UserFrom\":31,\"type\":\"shortlist\",\"date\":1494592599789}"}

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
 at com.xanadutec.coreflex.notification.NotificationDaoImpl.sendSortListedFcmNotification(NotificationDaoImpl.java:292)
 at com.xanadutec.coreflex.notification.NotificationServiceImpl.sendSortListedFcmNotification(NotificationServiceImpl.java:45)
 at com.xanadutec.coreflex.KitUpgradeAndPayment.KitUpgradeAndPaymentController$1.run(KitUpgradeAndPaymentController.java:393)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
 at com.xanadutec.coreflex.notification.NotificationDaoImpl.sendSortListedFcmNotification(NotificationDaoImpl.java:287)
 ... 3 more
```

I had done connection code here:

```
String url = fcmNotification.getUrl();
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();


                // add reuqest header
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", fcmNotification.getAuthorization());
                con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");

                // Send post request
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(body.toString());
                wr.flush();

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            //  System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            //  System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
            //  System.out.println(body.toString());

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
```

Can anyone help me. I am not able to send notification.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By any chance does the message you're sending contain non-ASCII characters? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352133/server-side-gcm-returns-error-400?rq=1